# <div> still working after being closed

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm making some stats for my website and those are in 3 tables. 
To make it look pretty, I made them on the same line.

So I'm creating 3 tables with different `<div>` and the code looks like that :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
}

<center><h1>TimeSheet Statistics</h1></center>
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.tab)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        j=j+1;
        @Html.Raw(string.Format("<div id='id{0}' style='float:left; margin-right: 1%;width:31%;display: inline;'>", j));
        @Html.Raw("<table style='border-collapse:collapse;'>");
        @Html.Raw("<tr align='center'><td style='border:1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/'>Client Name</a></td><td style='border:1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/u'>Units Live</a></td><td style='border:1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/p'>% Live</a></td><td style='border:1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/i'>Tot.Inter.</a></td><td style='border:1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/m'>Month Inter.</a></td></tr>");
    }
    i = i + 1;
    if (item.getPackageUnitsLive() < 0)
    {
        @Html.Raw("<tr class='colored' style='color:red'>");
    }
    else
    {
        if (item.getPackageUnitsLive() <= 10)
        {
            @Html.Raw("<tr class='colored' style='color:orange'>");
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.Raw("<tr class='colored'>");
        }
    }
    <td><a align='center' style='font-size:11px' class='tdColored' href='/Customers/Details/@item.getClientRef()'>@item.getClientName()</a></td>
    <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'>@if(item.getPackageUnitsLive()>=0){@item.getPackageUnitsLive()@Html.Raw("/")@item.getPackageTypePackage(); }else{ Html.Raw("&nbsp;");}</td>
    <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'>@if(item.getPercentLive()>=0){@item.getPercentLive()@Html.Raw("%")}else{ Html.Raw("&nbsp;");}</td>
    <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'>@if(item.getNbrInterventionsUnits() > 0){@item.getNbrInterventionsUnits()}else{ Html.Raw("&nbsp;");}</td>
    <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'>@if(item.getNbrInterventionsUnitsMonth() > 0){@item.getNbrInterventionsUnitsMonth()}else{ Html.Raw("&nbsp;");}</td>
    @Html.Raw("</tr>")
    if (i > ViewBag.nbClients / 3)
    {
        i = 0;
        @Html.Raw("</table>")
        @Html.Raw("</div>")
    }
}
@Html.Raw("</table>")@Html.Raw("</div>")
```

I have three tables like I wanted but the problem is when I launch the code, my footer is going in the last table even I closed the last `<div>`...

What did I do wrong ?

Thanks in advance !

EDIT : There is the output:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TimeSheet</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/core.css"
          rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Scripts/jquery-ui.css"
          rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/theme.css"
          rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">TimeSheet</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/Customers">Liste Clients</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Interventions/techByDay">Int. Tech/Day</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Statistiques">Statistiques</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="/Account/SignIn" id="loginLink">Sign in</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
      <center><h1>TimeSheet Statistics</h1></center>
      <div id='id1' style='float:left; margin-right: 1%;width:31%;display: inline;'><table style='border-collapse:collapse;'><tr align='center'><td style='border:1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/'>Client Name</a></td><td style='border:1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/u'>Units Live</a></td><td style='border:1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/p'>% Live</a></td><td style='border:1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/i'>Tot.Inter.</a></td><td style='border:1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/m'>Month Inter.</a></td></tr><tr class='colored' style='color:red'>    <td><a align='center' style='font-size:11px' class='tdColored' href='/Customers/Details/ANT'>Antoine et Fils</a></td>
        <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
        <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
        <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'>30</td>
        <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'>30</td>
        </tr><tr class='colored' style='color:red'>    <td><a align='center' style='font-size:11px' class='tdColored' href='/Customers/Details/CHA'>Chalet de la Foret</a></td>
        <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
        <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
        <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
        <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
        </tr><tr class='colored' style='color:red'>    <td><a align='center' style='font-size:11px' class='tdColored' href='/Customers/Details/CHR'>Christian &amp; Cie</a></td>
        <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
        <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
        <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
        <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
        </tr><tr class='colored' style='color:red'>    <td><a align='center' style='font-size:11px' class='tdColored' href='/Customers/Details/DAM'>Damien CORP</a></td>
        <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
        <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
        <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
        <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
        </tr><tr class='colored' style='color:red'>    <td><a align='center' style='font-size:11px' class='tdColored' href='/Customers/Details/FAB'>Fabian.Oli</a></td>
        <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
        <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
        <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
        <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
        </tr></table></div><div id='id2' style='float:left; margin-right: 1%;width:31%;display: inline;'><table style='border-collapse:collapse;'><tr align='center'><td style='border:1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/'>Client Name</a></td><td style='border:1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/u'>Units Live</a></td><td style='border:1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/p'>% Live</a></td><td style='border:1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/i'>Tot.Inter.</a></td><td style='border:1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/m'>Month Inter.</a></td></tr><tr class='colored' style='color:red'>    <td><a align='center' style='font-size:11px' class='tdColored' href='/Customers/Details/GUI'>Guillaume </a></td>
      <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
      <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
      <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'>2</td>
      <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'>2</td>
      </tr><tr class='colored' style='color:red'>    <td><a align='center' style='font-size:11px' class='tdColored' href='/Customers/Details/JOS'>Joseph industries</a></td>
      <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
      <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
      <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
      <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
      </tr><tr class='colored' style='color:red'>    <td><a align='center' style='font-size:11px' class='tdColored' href='/Customers/Details/NIC'>Nicolas.leo</a></td>
      <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
      <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
      <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
      <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
      </tr><tr class='colored' style='color:red'>    <td><a align='center' style='font-size:11px' class='tdColored' href='/Customers/Details/PIE'>Pierre Group</a></td>
      <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
      <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
      <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
      <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
      </tr><tr class='colored'>    <td><a align='center' style='font-size:11px' class='tdColored' href='/Customers/Details/TST0'>TST0</a></td>
      <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'>30/30</td>
      <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'>100%</td>
      <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
      <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
      </tr></table></div><div id='id3' style='float:left; margin-right: 1%;width:31%;display: inline;'><table style='border-collapse:collapse;'><tr align='center'><td style='border:1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/'>Client Name</a></td><td style='border:1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/u'>Units Live</a></td><td style='border:1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/p'>% Live</a></td><td style='border:1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/i'>Tot.Inter.</a></td><td style='border:1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/m'>Month Inter.</a></td></tr><tr class='colored'>    <td><a align='center' style='font-size:11px' class='tdColored' href='/Customers/Details/TST1'>TST1</a></td>
      <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'>30/30</td>
      <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'>100%</td>
      <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
      <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
      </tr><tr class='colored'>    <td><a align='center' style='font-size:11px' class='tdColored' href='/Customers/Details/XXX4'>XXX4</a></td>
      <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'>30/30</td>
      <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'>100%</td>
      <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
      <td align='center' style='font-size:11px'></td>
      </tr></table></div>
      <hr />
      <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2016 - TimeSheet</p>
      </footer>
    </div>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT : This is how it's look, the footer in on the left

[image: Footer is on the left...]

Comment: Copy + Paste your output html to a validation tool and check what's wrong..

Comment: @MoshFeu Nothing wrong with the validation tools... Only obsolete tags but nothing else

Comment: Double check your brace matching; that one before `i = i + 1` looks wrong...

Comment: Can you show us your output html?

Comment: @MoshFeu good Idea I just added it with a picture too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the div `#id1`, `#id2` and `#id3` has `float:left`. This is a very known problem. You can read more about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/).

In short: You need to clear the floating by wrapping them with container such as `div` and make it clear.

In this demo I wrapped them with div with class [`.clearfix`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/).

```css
.clearfix:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
/* start commented backslash hack \*/
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
/* close commented backslash hack */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TimeSheet</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

    <link href="/Content/themes/base/core.css"
          rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Scripts/jquery-ui.css"
          rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Content/themes/base/theme.css"
          rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">TimeSheet</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/Customers">Liste Clients</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Interventions/techByDay">Int. Tech/Day</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Statistiques">Statistiques</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="/Account/SignIn" id="loginLink">Sign in</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">


      <div class="clearfix">
        <center><h1>TimeSheet Statistics</h1></center>
        <div id='id1' style='float: left; margin-right: 1%; width: 31%; display: inline;'>
          <table style='border-collapse: collapse;'>
            <tr align='center'>
              <td style='border: 1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/'>Client Name</a></td>
              <td style='border: 1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/u'>Units Live</a></td>
              <td style='border: 1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/p'>% Live</a></td>
              <td style='border: 1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/i'>Tot.Inter.</a></td>
              <td style='border: 1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/m'>Month Inter.</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class='colored' style='color: red'>
              <td><a align='center' style='font-size: 11px' class='tdColored' href='/Customers/Details/ANT'>Antoine et Fils</a></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'>30</td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'>30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class='colored' style='color: red'>
              <td><a align='center' style='font-size: 11px' class='tdColored' href='/Customers/Details/CHA'>Chalet de la Foret</a></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class='colored' style='color: red'>
              <td><a align='center' style='font-size: 11px' class='tdColored' href='/Customers/Details/CHR'>Christian &amp; Cie</a></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class='colored' style='color: red'>
              <td><a align='center' style='font-size: 11px' class='tdColored' href='/Customers/Details/DAM'>Damien CORP</a></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class='colored' style='color: red'>
              <td><a align='center' style='font-size: 11px' class='tdColored' href='/Customers/Details/FAB'>Fabian.Oli</a></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div id='id2' style='float: left; margin-right: 1%; width: 31%; display: inline;'>
          <table style='border-collapse: collapse;'>
            <tr align='center'>
              <td style='border: 1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/'>Client Name</a></td>
              <td style='border: 1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/u'>Units Live</a></td>
              <td style='border: 1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/p'>% Live</a></td>
              <td style='border: 1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/i'>Tot.Inter.</a></td>
              <td style='border: 1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/m'>Month Inter.</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class='colored' style='color: red'>
              <td><a align='center' style='font-size: 11px' class='tdColored' href='/Customers/Details/GUI'>Guillaume </a></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'>2</td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'>2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class='colored' style='color: red'>
              <td><a align='center' style='font-size: 11px' class='tdColored' href='/Customers/Details/JOS'>Joseph industries</a></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class='colored' style='color: red'>
              <td><a align='center' style='font-size: 11px' class='tdColored' href='/Customers/Details/NIC'>Nicolas.leo</a></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class='colored' style='color: red'>
              <td><a align='center' style='font-size: 11px' class='tdColored' href='/Customers/Details/PIE'>Pierre Group</a></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class='colored'>
              <td><a align='center' style='font-size: 11px' class='tdColored' href='/Customers/Details/TST0'>TST0</a></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'>30/30</td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'>100%</td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div id='id3' style='float: left; margin-right: 1%; width: 31%; display: inline;'>
          <table style='border-collapse: collapse;'>
            <tr align='center'>
              <td style='border: 1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/'>Client Name</a></td>
              <td style='border: 1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/u'>Units Live</a></td>
              <td style='border: 1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/p'>% Live</a></td>
              <td style='border: 1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/i'>Tot.Inter.</a></td>
              <td style='border: 1px solid #728a8e'><a class='upsize' href='/Statistiques/Index/m'>Month Inter.</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class='colored'>
              <td><a align='center' style='font-size: 11px' class='tdColored' href='/Customers/Details/TST1'>TST1</a></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'>30/30</td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'>100%</td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class='colored'>
              <td><a align='center' style='font-size: 11px' class='tdColored' href='/Customers/Details/XXX4'>XXX4</a></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'>30/30</td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'>100%</td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
              <td align='center' style='font-size: 11px'></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr />
      <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2016 - TimeSheet</p>
      </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/joxewu/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Nice this is the answer thank you very much ! Didn't now that float will be so annoying to kill ^^ Thanks !

Comment: ;) Yes, `floating` is so problematic. [`flex`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) do this better, but it's not [cross brwoser yet](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) :(